# I have 3 dimension reduction methods and 3 classifiers, how to select the best combination?

Tags: model-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to classify two types of objects, which unfortunately have high-dimensional features with few samples. (230 features 12 samples from each group).

As a first step:
To reduce the dimension, I have tested three different approaches of PCA (each with slightly different  parameters)  and use the scores of the first 3 PCs as the features instead of the original 230 features.

As a second step:
in order to classify those objects, I have tested three different classifiers (SVM, 3-NN, Naive Bayes) where I use the leave one out method, i.e.: training the classifier on 23 objects and tested it on the one leave out, for testing.

Sum up: I have use 3 different dimensional reduction methods and three use different classifiers (nine combinations overall).

In one combination (out of 9), I got excellent classification performance.

My question: Is there some statistic approach I can use here in order to prove that this option was indeed robust and the correct one, and didn't happen by chance?

Comment: + please forgive me that I am not a native English speaker :)

Comment: You have only 24 objects and reduced the set to 3 attributes? This is quite harsh.

Comment: Yep, but what I didn't mention is that 230 features are 230 sample points of [EEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography)  data (of 24 subjects i.e. that data is highly correlate ?).  And then explained variance of the first three PC (i.e. my model) is about 85%. i think it good enough, isn't it ?

Comment: In this case, you should rather use descriptors like signal energy, Fourier coefficients, wavelet spectra etc. The fact that 3 PCs explain 85% of variance does not mean it preserve 85% of information.

Comment: Thanks! Can you further elaborate when you say " PCs explain 85% of variance does not mean it preserve 85% of information" can you point me to a reference for this ?

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure Fourier will work well on EEG signals. wavelet might do better. http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=eeg%20signals%20non%20stationary&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F9639%2F30462%2F01403164.pdf%3Farnumber%3D1403164&ei=iHqoTspR04riBOTJ0Ao&usg=AFQjCNFbRfdiyypaAwiG7E0ESZWnDSROJw&sig2=38gt0ytUb8YGeaxZeWxgRg&cad=rja

Comment: It is quite obvious -- PCA does not depend on decision. Yet I'll try to find some reference. About selecting descriptors, this was a general remark -- but I'm sure you'll easily find what is suitable for EEG. You can even try asking here.

Comment: Thanks, highly appreciate all your help. Maybe you can also help me with my main question here?

Comment: Comment1: 12 samples (patients) is a very small sample size. Besides the question whether you can train a good model on so few patients (which will depend on the between class : within class variance) you won't be able to show that the classifier works well: if you get 11 of your 12 patients in that group correctly classified, that is a sensitivity of 92%, but the 95% confidence interval goes from 62% - 100%. How do you pick the best of those nine models which have all comparable uncertainty on their measured performance?

Comment: Comment2: If you do a data-driven pre-processing where the calculation depends on all EEGs (such as PCA), you need to include this pre-processing step inside the cross validation. Otherwise, your CV results will be too optimistic: the data is not independent any longer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all make sure that classification is really the goal (vs. prediction), e.g., you don't care if a predictor combination that yields a probability of 0.5 is arbitrarily put into one of the two classes.  Second, obtain an adequate sample size.  Third, statistical principles often tell you that one prediction method is expected to be nearly optimal.  Question the need for multiple methods.

Comment: First, highly appreciated your comment! Searching the web for the definition of classification and prediction: (admit that I wasn't aware of this different)  I have found that classification  predicts categorical class labels while prediction is used for  Models continuous-valued functions. If the above definition is correct, I'm talking about classification here.

Comment: Can you further elaborate when you say "you don't care if a predictor combination that yields a probability of 0.5 is arbitrarily put into one of the two classes" and also on ", statistical principles often tell you that one prediction method is expected to be nearly optimal. Question the need for multiple methods." thanks in advance!

Comment: Prediction doesn't refer to the nature of the dependent variable per se.  It refers to having a continuous result for the predictions, e.g., a predicted probability that someone will be in class B given they are in either class A or class B.  An excellent probability modeling method (e.g., logistic model with appropriate nonlinearities and shrinkage) is a good choice.  The goal of the analyst, most of the time, should be to give optimal predictions.  The decision maker should decide what to do with the predictions.  E.g., a probability of 0.5 may indicate "get more data".

Comment: thanks again for your time! I have a discrete result for the predictions. -- so, I guess I'm in the classification case..

Comment: "probability of 0.5 may indicate get more data" --> but what can I do if with one model I'm having a probability of 0.5 and with slightly different model I got a probability of 0.9

Comment: I would derive a single model based on best practices and principles.  You may have predictions with lots of ties in their values but that doesn't mean that forced-choice classification is in order.

Comment: I guess you right.